# Map with duplicate key but with different values?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way to use map or any other collection which allow us to store duplicate keys
with different values...
rather then using a List to store multiple values for same key?

Comment: `Map<Key, List>` is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. How would you look up the value of that key if the key pointed to multiple values?

Comment: I think the best question to ask here is. When you call `map.get(key)`, and the map contains multiple of `key`. What do you expect to be returned?

Comment: Implement your own Map, but I don't see meaning in that. What's the logic behind what you seek, that Map with key and list cannot provide?

Comment: can you give a little view to the scenario you are facing , that brings you to have this requirement

Comment: I think you need to utilize the `HashMap<K,V>` which accepts null K and V of course, but beware because it's not THREAD-SAFE

Comment: The purpose of maps is not to have duplicate keys, why would you want to do otherwise is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map doesn't allow you to have duplicated keys. That even doesn't make sense.

Possible solution is having `list`(Collection) of `values`. Just go for it.If anything stopping you, let us know.

Comment: Ok,,Got it going with the approach having list of values with same key Just wanted to know wheather there is any approach better then this..

Comment: Not sure about 'any approach better'; this actually sounds like the right approach.  Depending on context though, a Map<K,Set<V>> might be better sometimes.  Does the order of the values matter?  Are there duplicates (for any given key)?  Using TreeSet (naturally ordered) or LinkedHashSet (insertion order) might be useful, sometimes, too.

Comment: @Paul Understood your intention :) list of values in the sense, Having a collection of values for single key. That selecting Collection is next step. +1. Nice point thought. The first Doubt of OP Pankaj is to go for a Collection or not.

Answer (score 8):

Use Google Guava's MultiMap. This allows multiple values with single key

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: +1, but OP should realise that this is effectively `rather then using a List to store multiple values for same key?`

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Multimap` concept. For example in guava. [Multimap in guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

But it's not a part of Collection framework.

If you would not like signature like this `Map<String, List<Item>>`, you could easily wrap it with object. E.g.

```
class Items {
   private List<Item> items;
   public void add(Item i) {}
}
```

Of course it would not be possible to add items through map instance as `map.add("key", item)`

Answer (score 0):

What about the next?:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Add values

```
// add "key1" and "value1"
if (!map.containsKey("key1")) {
    map.put("key1", new ArrayList<String>());
}
map.get("key1").add("value1");

// add "key1" and "value2"
if (!map.containsKey("key1")) {
    map.put("key1", new ArrayList<String>());
}
map.get("key1").add("value2");
```

#### Get values

```
List<String> values = map.get("key1");
```

---

This with string, but can be for any type. And you don't need additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MultiMap from apache commons collections

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html